Junit error Can't load log handler "1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler"
Getting below error while running junit.
Can't load log handler "1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) 

All search links suggesting to modify vm variable -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager in tomcat. But how running junit is depend on the tomcat server I added.
How to fix above issue?
